# while looping vs foreach looping

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Im trying to print it in excel but I dont get it why the **foreach loop** give me an **Warning: Illegal string offset** but in **while loop** it just run smoothly

this is the **while loop**

**EDITED**

```
include 'db.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$excel = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $wew = $row["fname"]."\t".$row["lname"]."\t".$row["email"];
    array_push($excel,$wew);
}

echo implode("\n",array_values($excel));
```

This is my **foreach loop**

```
include 'db.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$excel = array();

foreach($row as $r){
    $wew = $r["fname"]."\t".$r["lname"]."\t".$r["email"];
    array_push($excel,$wew);
}

echo implode("\n",array_values($excel));
```

Im trying to understand it but couldn't find how solve this one.

Comment: because your while loop is using `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII my foreach loop does using mysql_fetch_array

Comment: you will only get one row using foreach output the results, and compare

Comment: @JeffPuckettII sorry forgot to edit

Comment: btw, it's high time you switched to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Im just studying the flow but dont worry ill be using that coz im thinking using CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$r` is of `string` type and not an `array` so:

```
foreach($row as $r){
    $wew = $row["fname"]."\t".$row["lname"]."\t".$row["email"];
    array_push($excel,$wew);
}
```

**OR**

```
$wew = "";
foreach($row as $r){
    $wew .= $row["fname"]."\t".$row["lname"]."\t".$row["email"]; 
}
array_push($excel,$wew);
```

Comment: This will give only one result, as opposed to the while loop which is fetching all the results. You will get duplicate rows, one for every column in the result set this way.

Comment: thank you sir so this is why if im using $r give me illegal string coz im already using a string

Comment: I am sure the first one will work, not just that sure about that second.

Comment: Good to know. Good luck further.